# MSYS2 on Windows 10 - cannot update the package database using pacman

Tags: windows, gtk3, msys2, msys, pacman-package-manager

I tried to update my MSYS2 on Windows 10 (as per the instructions on https://www.msys2.org/) and I got this error:

```
OscarAlvarez@Lambda-Station-OA MINGW64 ~
$ pacman -Syu
error: config file /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist.mingw could not be read: No such file or directory
```

So I did a fresh install of MSYS2 on Windows 10. I got the binaries from the MSYS2 website and installed it successfully. Now, I am getting the same error.

I went into the /etc/pacman.d/ directory and this is what was inside:

```
OscarAlvarez@Lambda-Station-OA MINGW64 /etc/pacman.d
$ ls
gnupg  mirrorlist.clang64  mirrorlist.mingw32  mirrorlist.mingw64  mirrorlist.msys  mirrorlist.ucrt64
```

I didn't find the file so I created an empty file with the name "mirrorlist.mingw" and ran the update but to no avail. So I just deleted the empty file I created. No other flags like -S, -Su, or -Syy, etc. work and produce the same error.

Is there any way to fix this? My goal is to install GTK3 or 4 so I can develop using gtk-fortran on Windows.

Thank you.

Comment: Report this to the bug tracker, if nobody did it yet.

Comment: Okay, I will look up how to do that.

Comment: Post here: https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages/issues

Comment: I posted the bug, Thank you.